# fcom/fcompp and fstatsw different results

Tags: windows, fasm, fpu

I just starting using FPU and found some interesting moment.
Correct me if I'm wrong, we have only 8 ST's (0-7). We can operate with only 8 float values with them.
Here is the simple code:

```
fldz; ST0 = 0
fld1; ST0 = 1, ST1 = 0
fcompp
fstatsw ax
```

The value of the AX depends (in my case) on count of stored values in ST's.
I have to get 0 at the AX, and it is if I call it in the begin of my code.
But after some calculation using the FPU commands I started to get interesting values (if ST0 greater then ST1):

```
count | AX
------+------
    2 | 4000h
    3 | 3800h
    4 | 3000h
    5 | 2800h
    6 | 2000h
    7 | 1800h
    8 | 1000h
```

In other words, if I have 2 elements in ST's the result is 4000h; 3 elements - 3800h and etc. And we compare ST0 and ST1 always.

How it possible? Or I might forget something?
For other comparison results (equal and less then), I see the same behavior, but with another numbers.

If ST0 equal ST1:

```
count | AX
------+------
    2 | 8000h
    3 | 7800h
    4 | 7000h
    5 | 6800h
    6 | 6000h
    7 | 5800h
    8 | 5000h
```

If ST0 less then ST1:

```
count | AX
------+------
    2 | 4100h
    3 | 3900h
    4 | 3100h
    5 | 2900h
    6 | 2100h
    7 | 1900h
    8 | 1100h
```

Environment:

```
Assembler: FASM
CPU: x64
Application: Windows GUI x86
```

Answer (score 0):

The FPU status word you're storing in `ax` includes the "top of stack" register number, so will change depending on the number of items in the register stack as well as the result of your `fcompp` instruction. If you want to inspect the status word to determine the result of the comparison you will need to extract the appropriate bits.

Note that if you want to use conditional branching instructions (`Jcc`) based on the result of the floating point comparison you may want to look at using one of the floating point comparison instructions that sets the regular `EFLAGS` register, e.g. `fcomip`.

Comment: I check C3,C2 and C0. And they are differ for different stack elements count.
I'll check the fcomip today.

Comment: @Vitaly without seeing the exact code you're using, it's difficult to determine what is wrong.

Comment: Solved. I checked ST registers values and TOP. As I understood, compared another numbers then expected. Step-by-step debug with checking ST registers after each command. Error was "began" a bit above in the code.